# CSS: position: absolute и transform: rotate на 90 или 270 градусов оставляет лишнее пустое пространство в IE 11 и Edge

Tags: html, css3, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, rotate

Ситуация следующая. Верстаю страницу, которая должна одинаково работать в браузерах IE 11, Edge, Google Chrome и Firefox.
Страница разделена на несколько блоков. Одну часть занимает блок, в который загружается изображение.
Все изображения, которые будут загружаться, прямоугольные и разного размера. По умолчанию размер изображения подгоняется под 100% ширины блока.
Основной функционал, который доступен пользователю при работе с изображением следующий: поворачивать его на 90, 180, 270 и 360 градусов, пропорционально увеличивать и уменьшать масштаб на 5% от текущего значения. Если изображение не помещается в блок, то появляется скролл, позволяющий пользователю просмотреть всё изображение.
Всё отлично работает, кроме поворота изображения на 90 и 270 градусов в браузерах IE 11 и Edge.
Пример проблемы:

```css
.image-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  right: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 55%;
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
}

#Left {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

#ImageLeft {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
  transform-origin: top left;
  display: block;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <div id="Left" class="rotate0">
      <img id="ImageLeft" src="https://cdn.tutsplus.com/vector/uploads/legacy/qt/qt_35_isometric_grid/2.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Если опустить вертикальный скролл до самого низа, то *в IE 11 и Edge будет лишнее пустое пространство между изображением и концом блока*. **Его не должно быть и его нет в Google Chrome и Firefox!**
Создается ощущение, что IE 11 и Edge не до конца понимает, что изображение повернуто.
В последние 2 недели упорно гуглил данную проблему, но работающего для себя решения так и не нашел. Людям помогает display: block или связка position: relative на родительском элементе + position: absolute на проблемном, указание top, left, right, bottom, различных margin, и даже DOCTYPE. Но мне ничего не помогает... :(
Как всё-таки избавиться от лишнего пустого пространства, после поворота на 90 или 270 градусов, в IE 11 и Edge?
Я только начинаю осваивать верстку HTML, поэтому прошу камнями не закидывать, если проблема банальна.

Comment: У меня в последней версии Edge все работает... Что касается IE, то мне кажется, что у него баг с обновлением scrollHeight. Вообще на IE в 2020-ом можно потихоньку забивать, его мировая доля около 1% и она постоянно снижается.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, версию Edge, на которой проблема не проявляется. Возможно удастся пробить установку обновлений для Win10 в нашей организации, т.к. последние крупное обновление 2004 до сих пор не установлено точно.  И т.к. в нашей организации используется внутреннее ПО, которое работает только на IE, то, к сожалению, я не могу "забить" на поддержку этого древнего браузера... (((

Comment: Microsoft Edge Version 85.0.564.44 (Official build) (64-bit). Ниже предложу ответ - вариант, который стоит попробовать...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Огромное спасибо **NoSkill** за идею реализации!
Всё получилось! Проверял на браузерах IE 11, Egde, Firefox, Chrome. Привожу рабочий пример.
Стили:

```css
           .image-wrapper {
              position: absolute;
              top: 40px;
              left: 4px;
              right: 4px;
              bottom: 4px;
              width: 50%;
              height: 55%;
              overflow: auto;
              display: block;
            }
            
            #Left {
                position: relative;
                overflow: hidden;
                display: block;
            }
            
            #ImageLeft {
                position: absolute; 
                top: 0px; 
                bottom: 0px; 
                display: block;
                transform-origin: top left;
            }
            
            #Left.rotate90 #ImageLeft {
                transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
            }
            #Left.rotate180 #ImageLeft {
                transform: rotate(180deg) translate(-100%, -100%);
            }
            #Left.rotate270 #ImageLeft {
                transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
            }
```

html

```html
        <button type="button" onclick="rotateIMG('ImageLeft', 1)">Поворот на 90° по часовой</button>
        <div class="image-wrapper">
            <div id="Left" class="rotate0">
                <img id="ImageLeft" scl="100" onload="turnImage('ImageLeft');" src="https://cdn.tutsplus.com/vector/uploads/legacy/qt/qt_35_isometric_grid/2.jpg" >
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS

```js
             function scrollbarWidth() {
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.style.overflowY = 'scroll';
                div.style.width = '50px';
                div.style.height = '50px';
                document.body.appendChild(div);
                var scrollWidth = div.offsetWidth - div.clientWidth;
                document.body.removeChild(div);
                return scrollWidth;
            };
            
            function turnImage(id) {
                var img = document.getElementById(id), imgW = img.naturalWidth, imgH = img.naturalHeight, scale = Number( img.getAttribute('scl') );
                var win = img.parentElement.parentElement, winW = win.offsetWidth - scrollbarWidth();
                var div = img.parentElement, deg = Number( div.classList[0].replace("rotate","") );
                if (deg == 90 || deg == 270) {
                    var coef = (winW / imgH), w = ((imgW * coef) * (scale / 100)), h = ((imgH * coef) * (scale / 100));
                } else {
                    var coef = (winW / imgW), w = ((imgW * coef) * (scale / 100)), h = ((imgH * coef) * (scale / 100));
                }
                //console.log('Ширина изображения: ' + imgW + 'px; высота изображения: ' + imgH + 'px; масштаб: ' + scale + '%; ширина блока для изображения (за вычетом ширины полосы прокрутки): ' + winW + 'px; коэффициент: ' + coef + '; угол поворота: ' + deg + ' градусов')
                
                img.setAttribute('style', 'width: ' + w + 'px; height: ' + h + 'px;');
                if (deg == 90 || deg == 270) {
                    div.setAttribute('style', 'width: ' + h + 'px; height: ' + w + 'px;');
                } else {
                    div.setAttribute('style', 'width: ' + w + 'px; height: ' + h + 'px;');
                }
            };
            
            function rotateIMG(id, r) {
                var img = document.getElementById(id);
                var div = img.parentElement;
                switch (div.classList[0]) {
                    case "rotate0": var angle = 0; div.classList.remove('rotate0'); break;
                    case "rotate90": var angle = 90; div.classList.remove('rotate90'); break;
                    case "rotate180": var angle = 180; div.classList.remove('rotate180'); break;
                    case "rotate270": var angle = 270; div.classList.remove('rotate270'); break;
                    default: var angle = 0; break;
                }
                if (r > 0) {
                    angle = (angle + 90) % 360;
                } else {
                    if (angle == 0) angle = 360;
                    angle = (angle - 90) % 360;
                }
                div.classList.add("rotate" + angle);
                turnImage(id);
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Если очень необходима поддержка IE, можете попробовать сделать вот что:

Поместите картинку в контейнер с `overflow: hidden`.

Оперелите пропорции картинки с помощью JS: `image.naturalWidth / image.naturalHeight`. А самой картинке задайте CSS: `width: 100%; height: 100%;`

И затем повесте обработчик на `window.onresize`, в котором корректируйте высоту  контейнера, так чтобы его пропорции были всегда равны пропорциям картинки с учетом текущего поворота картинки. Тогда пустое пространство будет срезаться самим контейнером.